MAXIFs( ) to get max-value based on an array of values
I have a table like:



Type
Value




A
11


A
3


B
1


C
7


B
11


C
8



Let's say I need to +MAXIF(Value, Criteria1=Type, Criteria1 = A&B)
How could I do this in excel? With MAXIF I can only do criteria for one letter in Type. The alternative I have is: MAX(MAXIF(value, Criteria1=Type, A); MAXIF(value, Criteria1=Type, B)
For sure there's a way to save all the work, using only +MAXIF only.
Thank you!

Something like: =MAXIFS(Table1[Value],Table1[Type],UNIQUE(Table1[Type])) maybe?

=MAX(MAXIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,{"A","B"}))?

Do you want to return the max for both or the max of both?  Basically with the data above for A and B, what would you expect the output to be?

@ScottCraner, max of both.

Then @BigBen formula is the way to go.
